# How to remove duplicate borders in group of elements?

Tags: css

I am not sure this is doable in CSS only. How can I apply CSS roles to the `.btn` s only when there are another group of `btn-group` in a container?

Like I would like to remove the bottom borders of first group `.btn`s when there are 2 groups like Group 2 and even top border when they are in group 3? without changing anything in group 1.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h4> Group 1</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<h4> Group 2</h4>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h4> Group 3</h4>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could upload an image of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative to the current answer. I am using the `~` selector to select any element with the class `.btn-group` that is after any element with the class `.btn-group` and then removing the `border-top` from the child buttons.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.btn-group ~ .btn-group button {
  border-top:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h4> Group 1</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<h4> Group 2</h4>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h4> Group 3</h4>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
.btn-group + .btn-group {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```